# How to late init non-nullable variables?

Tags: typescript

In my tests, I often have to declare a variable at the top, which I will use in the `beforeAll` and the `afterAll`.
Example:

```
describe('My test suite', () => {
  let app: Server;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    app = await Server.init();
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

The problem is that when I turn on `strictNullChecks`, I get a warning on the line `let app: Server;` "Assigning nullable value to non-nullable variable".
Is there an equivalent to the [late](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables) keyword in dart?

Of course, I can do `let app: Server | undefined;` but then I have to `app!.close()`.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

**Edit**
Here is the base tsconfig.json

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
  ]
}
```

I extended it to use it with ESLint:

```json
// tsconfig.eslint.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

And then my eslintrc.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ['airbnb-base'],
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json',
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'strict-null-checks',
  ],
  rules: {
    'strict-null-checks/all': 'warn',
    // Turn off no-shadow because of enum
    // See: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/325
    'no-shadow': 'off',
    'no-dupe-class-members': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-dupe-class-members': ['error'],
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': ['warn', {
      allowExpressions: true,
    }]
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the bang non-null assertion character before the `:` used to declare the type of a variable to tell the TypeScript system that you are handling the nullability:

```
describe('My test suite', () => {
  let app!: Server;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    app = await Server.init();
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I still get the warning. Is there something else I need to my tsconfig?

Comment: @Gpack Can you update your answer to include your TS Config? It shouldn't fail on using bang by default, at least I don't think so.

Comment: @Gpack Because it's ES Lint giving you the warning, you should just ignore the next line in ES Lint. There's really no other way except for disabling the `strict-null-checks` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

My work around for this is to ignore the rule in my specs.

`.eslintrc.js`

```
{
  ...,
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**spec.ts'],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      parserOptions: {
        project: 'tsconfig.json',
        sourceType: 'module',
      },
      rules: {
        'strict-null-checks/all': 'off',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```